# Disable and gray out a checkbox label in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Is there a way to disable and gray out the checkbox label as well once the checkbox becomes disabled using Bootstrap and Jquery?

```
<div class="checkbox">        
    <input id="accept" name="accept" type="checkbox" value="True">
    <label for="accept" class="control-label">Incremental</label>
</div>
```

I am now using the bellow code to disable the checkbox:

```
 $("#accept").prop("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do it with **CSS** only

```js
$("#accept").prop("disabled", true);
```

```css
input[type=checkbox][disabled] + label {
    color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox">
    <input id="accept" name="accept" type="checkbox" value="True">
    <label for="accept" class="control-label">Incremental</label>
</div>
```

Read http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

[Attribute selectors in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Comment: For everyone like me that have no idea what the + does and wondering why it is not working. The label element needs to be directly after the input element (not before).

Comment: And how is the css impacted if teh label is before the checkbox?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that setting the word disabled in the div "class" as well as in the input will do it.

```
<div class="checkbox disabled">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="" disabled>check Me</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap dose not provide such type facility, you can manage from your jQuery custom code

```
if($("#accept").has("[disabled]")){
  $("#accept").parent().find("label").css("color", "#dadada");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

```
$("#accept").addClass("disabled");
```

Comment: This doesn't change the label at all in Bootstrap 3.

Answer (score -2):

```
  $('label.control-label').addClass('disabled');
```

to disable as a button

```
 $('label.control-label').addClass('btn-disabled');
```

Comment: Both suggestion do nothing to the label in Bootstrap 3.